# Android checkbox listen for click before change

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a requirement where a checkbox is displayed for a specific setting. When the user taps on the checkbox, I want to display an alert dialog. The checkbox should then only change if the user taps on the confirm button (or similar).

My point is that the `OnCheckedChanged` listener only fires after the checkbox has changed state, whereas I want to listen for the click before it changes state.

Comment: do you tried setOnClickListener?

Comment: Seems as if you are going to have to write your own checkbox. or maybe you can try CheckedTextView which may have greater customization. Obviously you want tk decide when the tick is shown, and when the listener is called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `onTouchListener` and intercept `ACTION_DOWN` event for showing alert.
on users choice change checked state of you checkbox programatically.

example:

```
checkbox.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            //show alert
            return true; //this will prevent checkbox from changing state
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

then call `checkbox.setChecked(true);` or `checkbox.setChecked(false);` as user selects yes or no.`

Comment: IMO you should listen for `ACTION_UP` instead in case the user clicks down, then drags their finger off the checkbox before lifting. Most system components work this way.

Comment: @tir38 as we will be showing dialog immediately after event, user will not get a chance to drag the finger. And as we are asking for confirmation in alert there will not be a case user accidentally checking a check box

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(isChecked==true){
                   //Show your alert

                    }
                }else if(isChecked==false){
                    //Show your alert
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: If I use `OnCheckChangeListener` the UI will update before this is called. So even if I immediately revert the click by calling `setChecked(false)` there will still be a small "blip" on the screen as the checkbox changes

Answer (score 1):

If would suggest to use an OnTouchListener on the checkbox. If your condition is fulfilled then you can call checkBox.performClick().

Answer (score 1):

You can try it;

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if ( isChecked )
            {
                // do anything
                // perform logic
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `onClickListener` and set checkbox's `checked` state accordingly.

```
    myCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // createYourDialog
            // onPositiveButtonClicked
            myCheckBox.setChecked(true);
            // onNegativeButtonClicked
            myCheckBox.setChecked(false);

            // yourDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: If I used `OnClickListener` the UI will update before this is called. So even if I immediately revert the click by calling `setChecked(false)` there will still be a small "blip" on the screen as the checkbox changes states real quickly.