# How to limit checkbox selection

Tags: java, android

I'm making a simple quiz app with 5 questions. There are 2 correct answers and 6 checkboxes to choose from. How do I make it so that when 2 checkboxes are checked (for each question) the app stops the user from selecting any more and displays a Toast message stating that you can't check more than 2 checkboxes for each question?

This is my code (Java, in Android Studio):

```
package com.example.android.architecturequizapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

//method called when Submit&Grade button is clicked
public void submitAnswers(View view) {

    //EditText name
    EditText nameTypeTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_edit_text);
    String typeName = nameTypeTextBox.getText().toString();

    //Question 1: Name Question: Eiffel Tower
    RadioButton q1Name = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.q1_eiffel_tower_radio_button);
    boolean hasQ1NameCorrect = q1Name.isChecked();

    //Question 1: Location Question: Paris
    CheckBox q1Location1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q1_paris_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ1Location1Correct = q1Location1.isChecked();

    //Question 1: Location Question: France
    CheckBox q1Location2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q1_france_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ1Location2Correct = q1Location2.isChecked();

    //Question 2: Name Question: Colosseum
    RadioButton q2Name = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.q2_colosseum_radio_button);
    boolean hasQ2NameCorrect = q2Name.isChecked();

    //Question 2: Location Question: Rome
    CheckBox q2Location1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q2_rome_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ2Location1Correct = q2Location1.isChecked();

    //Question 2: Location Question: Italy
    CheckBox q2Location2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q2_italy_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ2Location2Correct = q2Location2.isChecked();

    //Question 3: Name Question: Tower of Pisa
    RadioButton q3Name = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.q3_tower_of_pisa_radio_button);
    boolean hasQ3NameCorrect = q3Name.isChecked();

    //Question 3: Location Question: Pisa
    CheckBox q3Location1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q3_pisa_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ3Location1Correct = q3Location1.isChecked();

    //Question 3: Location Question: Italy
    CheckBox q3Location2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q3_italy_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ3Location2Correct = q3Location2.isChecked();

    //Question 4: Name Question: Casa Batllo
    RadioButton q4Name = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.q4_casa_batllo_radio_button);
    boolean hasQ4NameCorrect = q4Name.isChecked();

    //Question 4: Location Question: Barcelona
    CheckBox q4Location1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q4_barcelona_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ4Location1Correct = q4Location1.isChecked();

    //Question 4: Location Question: Spain
    CheckBox q4Location2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q4_spain_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ4Location2Correct = q4Location2.isChecked();

    //Question 5: Name Question: Eiffel Tower
    RadioButton q5Name = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.q5_opera_house_radio_button);
    boolean hasQ5NameCorrect = q5Name.isChecked();

    //Question 5: Location Question: Sydney
    CheckBox q5Location1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q5_sydney_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ5Location1Correct = q5Location1.isChecked();

    //Question 5: Location Question: Australia
    CheckBox q5Location2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.q5_australia_checkbox);
    boolean hasQ5Location2Correct = q5Location2.isChecked();

    int questionsCorrect = calculateRightAnswers(hasQ1NameCorrect, hasQ1Location1Correct, hasQ1Location2Correct, hasQ2NameCorrect, hasQ2Location1Correct, hasQ2Location2Correct, hasQ3NameCorrect, hasQ3Location1Correct, hasQ3Location2Correct, hasQ4NameCorrect, hasQ4Location1Correct, hasQ4Location2Correct, hasQ5NameCorrect, hasQ5Location1Correct, hasQ5Location2Correct);

    //toast message for questions correct/score
    //less than 5 = poor results
    if (questionsCorrect <= 5) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Poor results! You scored " + questionsCorrect + "/15!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    } else if (questionsCorrect <= 10) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Average results! You scored " + questionsCorrect + "/15!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    } else if (questionsCorrect <= 14) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Good results! You scored " + questionsCorrect + "/15!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    } else {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Excellent! You scored " + questionsCorrect + "/15!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }

    //TextView message on bottom
    endQuiz(typeName);

}

//calculate total points scored on quiz
private int calculateRightAnswers(boolean q1Name, boolean q1Location1, boolean q1Location2, boolean q2Name, boolean q2Location1, boolean q2Location2, boolean q3Name, boolean q3Location1, boolean q3Location2, boolean q4Name, boolean q4Location1, boolean q4Location2, boolean q5Name, boolean q5Location1, boolean q5Location2) {
    //score before taking quiz
    int pointsScored = 0;

    //1 part of Q1 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q1Name) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q1 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q1Location1) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q1 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q1Location2) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q2 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q2Name) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q2 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q2Location1) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q2 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q2Location2) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q3 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q3Name) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q3 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q3Location1) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q3 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q3Location2) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q4 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q4Name) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q4 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q4Location1) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q4 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q4Location2) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q5 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q5Name) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q5 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q5Location1) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    //1 part of Q5 is correct = + 1 point
    if (q5Location2) {
        pointsScored = pointsScored + 1;
    }

    return pointsScored;
}

private String endQuiz(String nameTyped) {
    TextView endingMessageTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ending_message_text_view);
    String endQuizMessage = "Thank you " + nameTyped + " for completing the quiz!";
    endQuizMessage += "\nHope you enjoyed it!";
    endingMessageTextView.setText(endQuizMessage);
    return endQuizMessage;
}
```

I searched the internet for help but couldn't find anything on it. Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Use a counter which is incremented when any checkbox is checked and decremented when each one is unchecked.

Comment: User an `int` variable counter. By the way you have made the code complex the doing the same thing again and again. You could make a function and pass in the `String` of updated message ('excellent', 'good' etc) rather then repeating code again and again. And instead of using all those booleans you could have used an `Array` of `booleans` as your `booleans` are in sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `onTouchListener` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076697/android-checkbox-listen-for-click-before-change).

```
checkbox.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            // check if there are already two checkboxes selected
            // you can use checkbox.isChecked() and a loop for that
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Only two checkboxes allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true; //this will prevent checkbox from changing state
        }
        return false; // this is default and lets event propagate
    }
});
```

Another option might be disabling all unchecked checkboxes when the second checkbox gets set and enabling them again, when one is unchecked.